# Why is the SMM behavior different between firststeps.simics and qsp-client-core.simics?

Tags: simics

If I set a `SMM` breakpoint in `firststeps.simics` and examine the registers, it shows the expected `RIP = 0x8000` and `CS base = 0x30000`. But if I do the same thing in `qsp-client-core.simics`, it shows `RIP = 0xdffebe74` and `CS base = 0`, and I don't understand why.

Eventually I see the `SMBASE` get moved from `0x30000` to `0xdffcd000`. But it seems like what the X58 chipset manual says is the `TSeg`, doesn't get set to that same value, which is what I would expect. Any idea why the `TSeg` is never set?

```
simics> print -x %msr_ia32_smbase
0xdffcd000
simics> get-device-offset  board.mb.nb.core_misc.bank.pci_config 0xA8 4
0 (LE)
```

(Note: I tested this out on platforms up to skylake, and it seems to only behave this way on coffee lake which is what the `qsp-client-core.simics` defaults to)

Answer (score 1):

I just tried `firststeps.simics` and I can see that smm handler is relocated as well.
`smm_base` is `0x30000` at the first entry but it changes to `0xdffd3000` almost right away:

```
$ ./simics targets/qsp-x86/qsp-client-core.simics
simics> output-radix 16
simics> board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0]->smm_base
0x30000
simics> continue-seconds 30
simics> board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0]->smm_base
0xdffd3000
```

You can see that clearly from logs as well:

```
simics> board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0].log-group -disable MSR
board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0]:
 enabled log groups: "Intermediate code" "Performance hint" "Other" "VMX" "Hardware breakpoints" "Pin change" "FPU" "Exception" "VM-monitor" "MONITOR" "X86 other" "Default_Log_Group"
 disabled log groups: "MSR"
simics> board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0].log-level 2
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0]] Changing log level: 1 -> 2
simics> log-setup -time-stamp 
simics> c
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0x83939a 388559012} IA32_FEATURE_CONTROL set to 0x5
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdf353932 388714533} Cache flush (with write-back)
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdf353987 388714952} Cache flush (with write-back)
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdf353932 388781185} Cache flush (with write-back)
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdf353987 388781604} Cache flush (with write-back)
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdf5765f5 389274426} Cache flush (with write-back)
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdf57664a 389274845} Cache flush (with write-back)
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdef5ed20 393668159} Cache flush (with write-back)
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdef5ecf0 393668269} Cache flush (with write-back)
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdffebe6e 397678713} SMI raised
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdffe43a9 397679321} New SMM base: 0xdffd3000
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdefc3471 398242965} SMI raised
[board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] info] {board.mb.cpu0.core[0][0] 0xdefc3471 403646564} SMI raised
```

As you can see, first call to SMM handler changes smm_base which is rather typical thing to do.

I don't know about `Tseg` but hopefully I at least partially answered your question.